# Add new version scikit-learn to spyder

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, spyder

I have downloaded the newest version of scikit-learn (0.18), however, spyder keeps on using the previous version (0.17). How do I make the two compatible?

I have updated both distributions using Anaconda:

```
conda update spyder
conda update scikit-learn
```

**Edit**

Simply forcing Anaconda to install scikit-learn (0.18) did the trick:

```
 conda install scikit-learn=0.18
```

Comment: What is the python interpreter used in your Spyder? You can check that in the settings.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.4.

Comment: No, I mean, what is the path to your python interpreter. Is it something like /usr/bin/python, or something prefixed with anaconda ? You might have different versions of sklearn installed, e.g. one via conda and the other via pip.

Comment: Had it on Default, changed it to anaconda3/bin/python3, but still the same result.

Comment: Did you restart spyder? How do check the version, with sklearn.__version__ ? What is sklearn.__file__ ?

Comment: Yes, both spyder and computer. And checked it with sklearn.__version__ . 
sklearn.__file__ gives /home/usr/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py

Answer (score 0):

You may have different versions of sklearn installed (via pip and conda), and spyder using your /usr/bin/python instead of anaconda/bin/python: make sure that the interpreter selected in Spyder preferences is the anaconda one.